# Как кастомизировать цвет одного символа в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, настройка

Всех приветствую!

Решил в своём проекте плавно переписать CSS стили на синтаксис SCSS, в котором присутствуют амперсанды ("&") для обозначения элементов родителей. Так вот можно ли как-нибудь в моей VSCode изменить стандартный цвет амперсанда?

[image]

Суть в том, что в перемешку с селекторами амперсанды выгледят некрасиво и хотелось бы их выделить как-то иначе, а именно - изменить цвет. Подскажите, реализуемма ли эта идея в целом, изменить цвет одного лишь символа? Я предполагаю, что возможно, ведь в файлах .js амберсанды & в условиях окрашиваются белым.

[image]

Comment: VSCode не является IDE.

Comment: Вы можете нажать F1 и ввести `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`, дальше потыкать по тексту и определить какой `textmate scope` имеет данный "элемент" и поиграться с ними, чтобы изменить нужный.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, понял, исправил

Comment: Вы можете еще установить [SCSS BEM Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joloyonaha.scss-bem-support), и вы сможете перекрасить модификаторы и элементы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Спасибо за Вашу помощь!. Ваша наводка помогла решить вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коментариях мне подсказали куда копать и я разобрался с проблемой. Распишу подробно здесь, если кому-то понадобится поэкспериментировать с чем-то подобным. В моём решении, я изменил цвет области видимости текста "&", к которой так же относятся все двоеточия, точки с запятой, амперсанды и набираемый текст во всех .scss файлах. В целом, если есть желание, то с помощью данной настройки можно менять как цвет тегов, так и букв, цифр, знаков пунктуации и прочее.

(важное уточнение, работает именно в VSCode):

1. Открываем проект в редакторе, переходим к документу, в котором хотим перекрасить теги/символы/знаки и нажимаем `F1`, или набираем сочетание клавиш `ctrl` + `shift` + `P`;
2. В поисковике набираем "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" ("Разработчик: Проверка токенов редактора и областей" на русском);
3. Теперь при наведении указателя на необходимую сущность будет указана инофрмация о ней. Нам нужна облать видимости текста, копируем:

   [image]
4. Снова нажимаем `F1`, или набираем сочетание клавиш `ctrl` + `shift` + `P`;
5. В поисковике набираем "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)" ("Открыть пользовательские настройки (JSON)" на русском). Откроется JSON докумет, с нечто подобным:

   [image]
6. Затем нам нужно добавить новый объект "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" и кастомизировать текст, указав при этом область видимости и необходимые настройки цвета:

   ```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                // Область видимости, которую мы скопировали
                "scope": ["entity.name.tag.reference.scss",
                          "meta.property-list.scss",
                          "source.css.scss"],
                // Настройки              
                "settings": {
                    // В моём случае, хочу поменять на этот цвет
                    "foreground": "#C586C0"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
   ```
7. Экспериментально определил, что для изменения цвета достаточно и первой области "entity.name.tag.reference.scss", но я добавил все три, как на скриншоте выше. По итогу, документ `settings.json` должен выглядеть приблизительно так:

   [image]
8. Готово, данными конкретными настройками определились цвета набираемого текста, амперсанда, двоеточия и точки с заятой:

   [image]